# AsyncTask и цикл

Tags: android, циклы

Требуется скачать н-ное количество изображений с сервера и добавить их в массив. У меня есть метод, который загружает изображение и возвращает `Bitmap`. Будет ли работать такой код?

```
int i = 0;
Bitmap[] bmp = new Bitmap[10];
for (i = 0; i < bmp.size(); i++) {
        new DownloadImage("урл до изображения") {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                bmp[i] = result;
                super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        }.execute(""); 
}
```

Насколько я понимаю - практически одновременно запустится 10 потоков и после того как первое изображение загрузится - переменная i давно будет равна 9-ти, соответственно элементу массива с индексом 2 не присвоится результат потока который запустился вторым по счету. Либо если допустим первое изображение будет занимать 500 кб, а второе 20 кб. Потоки ведь выполняются параллельно, соответственно второе изображение загрузится первей. Так ведь?

Comment: Этот код даже не скомпилируется.

1. `Bitmap[]` не имеет метода `size()`, видимо, имелось в виду `length`.

2. Попытка обратиться к non-final переменной внутри inner class.

Comment: Да, имелось в виду length.

Comment: если это не учебное задание, то стоит обратить внимание на [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: Кому интересно - то, что мне помогло: https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень хороший вопрос, над которым следует подумать, как следует.

Как известно, количество потоков, которые могут выполняться одновременно( параллельно ) зависит от количества ядер процессора( лишь в этом случае будет происходить реальное распараллеливание задач ). Но а что же будет, если потоков 10, а ядер, например, 2? Тогда будет происходить "иллюзия" распараллеливания. Да, да, именно она, так как в таком случае за очень короткий промежуток времени будут поочередно выполняться по нескольку тактов( процессорных инструкций ) каждого потока. Т.е будет происходить переключение между потоками. Причем количество тактов одинаковое, следовательно, поток, задача которого меньше, должен выполниться быстрее.

Значит, поток, задача которого загрузить изображение размером 20кб, закончит свою работу скорее, чем поток, задача которого - изображение 500кб. Да, и это неоднозначно, ведь это еще зависит и от того, в каком порядке запускались потоки( иллюзия распараллеливания 10 потоков - дело все-таки серьёзное ). Так что, если важен порядок изображений, то лучше поменять логику работы.

Comment: А при загрузке из сети и вовсе неизвестно какой поток отработает раньше.      
Плюс встаёт вопрос определения окончания всех загрузок.

Comment: @0xFFh если считаете, что вопрос хороший, то это хороший повод поднять репутацию вопроса :)

Comment: > Плюс встаёт вопрос определения окончания всех загрузок.

А нет никакого вопроса. onPostExecute отрабатывает в главном потоке. Поэтому, перед стартом всех закачек заводим счетчик, которому присваиваем кол-во закачек. а в onPostExecute уменьшаем на 1. Если счетчик равен 0 - все, скачали.

Comment: @0xFF а мне очень интересно ваще предположение про переключение контекста между потоками. С чего вы взяли, что процессор отдает одинаковое количество процессорного времени для раздичных потоков? В связи с этим мне кажется, что утверждение про "Значит, поток, задача которого загрузить изображение размером 20кб, закончит свою работу скорее, чем поток, задача которого - изображение 500кб." не совсем корректно, даже если бы они были запущенны одновременно.

Comment: @jimpanzer, насколько знаю, обычно все именно так. Даже если предположить, что процессорное время для различных потоков неодинаковое, то получится, что один из потоков будет иметь наибольший приоритет перед другим( его суммарное процессорное время будет больше ), следовательно, иллюзия параллельности будет нарушена.

Comment: Если в ответе  @jimpanzer слово "Значит" заменить "скорее всего, но не 100% вероятностью", то все будет правильно.

Answer (score 0):

что хочу сказать косаемо задачи --

1. масивы я бы точно не использовал
2. хронить в памяти все что загружено это как-то вообще не правильно
3. [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) от Сергея Тарасевича с подобными задачами справляется на ура, тем более что расширяемость там на уровне.

вот набрасал сейчас. я бы делал как-нибудь так:

```
    public class ImageLoader {
    private final static Map<String, Bitmap> cache = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

    private static String[] urlRegistry = new String[] { "url1", "url2", "url3" };

    public static void startLoad() {
        for (String url : urlRegistry) {
            doLoad(url);
        }
        for (;;){
            checkOnFinish();
        }
    }

    private static boolean doLoad(String url) {
        Bitmap image = cache.get(url);
        boolean result = false;
        if (image == null) {
            new Thread(new Loader(url)).start();
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static void checkOnFinish(){
        //TODO check
    }

    static class Loader implements Runnable {
        private String url;

        public Loader(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (cache) {
                Bitmap image = cache.get(url);
                if (image == null) {
                    image = getBitmap();
                    cache.put(url, image);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * @return bitmap from net
         */
        private Bitmap getBitmap(){
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

реализовывать проверку состояния скореевсего вообще не нужно, 
  загрузили и выставили туда куда нужно.